# Quais são os códigos ascii das setas direcionais do teclado?

Tags: c

Estou trabalhando em um projeto em C e me deparei com o seguinte método

```
static void keyEvent( unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    /* quit if the ESC key is pressed */
    if( key == 0x1c ) {
        printf("*** %f (frame/sec)\n", (double)count/arUtilTimer());
        cleanup();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Preciso executar algumas funções ao clicar nas teclas direcionais <kbd>↑</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd><kbd>→</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>, tentei printar no console mas não obtive sucesso... Utilizo o código ASCII p/ pegar o clique nessas teclas? Se sim, quais são?

Comment: Eu ia falar p/ você printar e ver quais são as telas mas você disse que não conseguiu, o que aconteceu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2877857/6101515

Comment: @PauloHDSousa deu erro e simplesmente fechou o prog, talvez por causa do tipo da variável, tentei printf(key); dentro do keyEvento, antes do primeiro if.

Comment: Você pode achar na net o valor ASCII p/ essas teclas mas não é confiável, o melhor é você mesmo pegar, esses valores mudam dependendo do SO.

Comment: @JuniorNunes valeu, eu já tinha visto esse post, mas enfim, não encontrei nada aqui no SOpt com relação a isso, vi nesse mesmo post que utilizando OpenGL e GLUT existe por exemplo GLUT_KEY_UP, talvez seja esse o caminho...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essas teclas não possuem código "ASCII". A tabela ASCII se compõe de 128 caracteres, send 32 de controle e 96 imprimíveis - e os de controle contém só as teclas "digitáveis" - tipo "enter", "tab" - e algumas outras para as quais os teclados dos PCs atuais não tem teclas "beep", "form feed", etc...

Bom, só o teclado atual tem 104 teclas - a maior parte modificável com shift e/ou alt - e os próprios shift e alt não tem correspondência nessa tabela.

O que acontece é que o teclado manda um código de hardware para cada tecla pressionada, e o sistema operacional traduz e disponibiliza para programas esses sinais - mas isso é feito em camadas diferentes, e que código você obtém para qual tecla depende muito de qual chamada ao sistema você está fazendo.

O método do sistema operacional que você está usando é usado pela função de biblioteca de C que você usa para ler o teclado-  como você não colocou qual é a efetiva chamada para obter o código da tecla, não é possivel xpandir essa resposta com uma pesquisa sobre qual seriam os códigos disponibilizados para você.

A dica que fica é realemten imprimir o código que chega -e que, algumas funções de leituras, para essas teclas que não tem um código ASCII direto,  o S.O. disponibiliza um código de múltiplos bytes, e retorna um byte de cada vez para o seu programa.

Imprimir o código na tela é a melhor solução para você tentar isola-los:

```
static void keyEvent( unsigned char key, int x, int y) { 
    printf("Code: %02x\n", key);
}
```

Agora, preste atenção em outra dica: Não adianta investir um tempão numa super-interface para seu programa se ele só vai funcionar no CMD do Windows: a maior parte dessas funções dependem não só do sistema operacional e algumas vão depender do tipo de terminal.
Se o programa for realemten útil par alugma coisa: (1) power users estão acostumados com programas de terminal que funcionam só "de cima pra baixo"  - preferencialemente consumindo parâmetros de linah de comando, e com uma ou outra entrada de dados ocasional;  Usuários "não power"  esperam uma interface gráfica de qualquer forma.

Alias, se quiser ter uma interface legal,a  dica é fazer o programa em outra linguagem  - como Python, Java , Ruby e escolher uma biblioteca para interfaces gráficas (ou mesmo fazer o seu programa ser web-based). Mesmo que o seu programa tenha partes que sejam melhor fazer em C  (por exemplo, uma sequência de cálculo onde é melhor ter todo o controle do processador), você pode chamar funções isoladas de C a partir do programa feito nessas outras linguagens.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta e, principalmente, pelas dicas.

Comment: ENtão  - vi no seu comentário que você tentou `printf(key);`   - vai dar pau mesmo. C é uma linguagem que te dá todo o controle do computador, mas fica tudo por sua conta - as funções não tem polimorfismo ou "duck typing" que sao mecanismos que permitem que elas aceitem tipos de parametros diferentes. O primeiro parâmetro para printf tem que ser uma string, sempre.  (E um caractere é um dado "escalar" - enquanto que uma string é sempre acessada como um endereço de memória). A função chamada em C não tem como saber se voce passar  o par. errado. (Mas deve ter dado warning)